# Good tool for finding photo duplicates based on image data

Tags: windows, images, duplicate

What is a good (and preferably free) tool for finding photo duplicates based on the photos themselves?

So, not filename, filesize etc., but how the photos look like. It would be nice if it managed to match photos that were the same image, but not exactly the same size for example too.

Comment: I'm certain this question has been asked already - but I can't find it!

Comment: Found one, but it was for files in general. I would like a tool that finds images that are veery similar, not just those that are the exact same files, if you understand what I mean.

Comment: VisiPics is also a good tool recommended by makeuseof.com http://www.visipics.info/

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/311633/free-visual-similarity-image-for-a-local-hard-drive-search

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**SimilarImages**](https://tn123.org/simimages/) is a free application designed to find similar images (duplicates) on your hard drives.

**Description:**

This simple GUI will help you to easy check your images for duplicates
It includes the following Preferences:

- **Configurable Threshold**: You may change the threshold depending on your needs. Once analyzed you may change the threshold without having to analyzed images again (if you don't alter the list)
- **Three search types:**

  - **Normal Search** - which will compare all images with all other images
  - **Inclusive Search** - which will only compare images contained in same folder with each other
  - **Exclusive Search** - which will only compare images not contained in same folder
- **Semi-Automatic-Deletion**: You may choose a rule which will preselect a file in review mode, so that you don't have to compare all the file properties yourself. Furthermore you may use the Auto-delete 0-Files feature which will apply the rule on all image pairs which are most similar.
- **Result Cache** that will seamlessly cache all the generated data so that later searches for already analyzed files will be much faster.
- **Not-A-Match Database** that will remember all non-matches.

[image]

Comment: +1 The software looks very well, took the liberty to add some more info

Comment: you're more than welcome :)

Comment: FYI: Very buggy under Windows 7 x64

Comment: This looks like a bad link now. Anyone have an updated location for this software?

Comment: @Tom updated the link to a working one.

Answer (score 4):

GQView is free and can find duplicate images by similarity:

[image]

There is [a Windows port](http://gqview-win.sourceforge.net/), though I've only used it in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but an image compare tool is [Image Comparer](http://www.bolidesoft.com/imagecomparer.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found one at [CodePlex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePlex) which seems to find many duplicates at least. I am not sure if it has found any that are the same, but different size yet though.

- **[Similar images finder](http://similarimagesfinder.codeplex.com/)** - *.NET Image processing in C# and RGB projections*

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar [image search](http://www.mindgems.com/info/Image-Search.html) for my own photo library: [Duplicate Image Finder](http://www.mindgems.com/products/VS-Duplicate-Image-Finder/VSDIF-About.htm).

This tool can find similar images sometimes even better than search engines, but it works for your own photo library. Give it a try. They also provide a free duplicate file finder.

[image]