# Finding similar images in a directory

Tags: image-processing

What are good tools for windows for finding similar images (size and name varies) in a directory, and displaying them side by side, so I can choose which ones I wish to keep (deleting the other one) ?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/30088/good-tool-for-finding-photo-duplicates-based-on-image-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Duplicate images finder](http://www.codeplex.com/DupliFinder):

> This application can search through
>   your images collection and find
>   duplicates not only by file name or
>   size, but also by visual similarity.

[image]

Comment: **that** is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

[**AKS**](http://www.softforall.com/Utilities/FileDisk/AKS_Image_Comparer09040893.htm) and [**Beyond Compare**](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php) are great for side-by-side image comparison.

AKS:

[image]

Beyond Compare:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to create a clickable image directory containing an arbitrary collection of images:

```
convert  'vid:photos/random/*_orig.*' vid_index.html
```

See [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/vid_index.html) for an example output.  You could then open them side by side in firefox or an image editor.

Comment: How does that help me ? If I wanted to compare them manually, I could've opened them in thumbnail mode in firefox, side by side ... or have I misunderstood you in some way ?

Comment: well, it depends on how many images you have & how deep your directory tree is.  the nice thing about the vid format is that you could recursively descend a hierarchy & make a flat index.  Each image could have a caption with the iamge name, size, type, comment, whatever.  Gives you a venu to make your choice & delete.  If you want to do more complex comparisons (finding the difference between 2 images) you can do that too, with a different imagemagick command.

Comment: If you have few images to dealwith, frankly, I liked @harrymc's answer.