# Software that takes an image as input and searches a specified directory for similar images

Tags: images, search, photos, comparison, file-comparison

I'm looking for a program that lets me input an image and then search a directory for visually similar images (much like Google image search, except it compares the image with my the local files in the directory that I specify).

So I have an image and let the program process it. Then the program will output a list of visually similar images (in % for example).

Is there such software? I really need it to find an image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free visual similarity image for a local hard drive search?](http://superuser.com/questions/311633/free-visual-similarity-image-for-a-local-hard-drive-search)

Answer (score 0):

imgSeek should let you search by an approximate sketch or photo:

"imgSeek is a photo collection manager and viewer with content-based search and many other features. The query is expressed either as a rough sketch painted by the user or as another image you supply (or an image in your collection)"

http://sourceforge.net/projects/imgseek/

or Duplicate Finder is simpler if you have exact photos to search with:

http://www.duplicate-finder.com/photo.html

Answer (score 0):

See, there are many ways to serve your purpose from developing one of your own to using a 3rd party. But sometimes *it's better not to reinvent the wheel though*, So, I am sharing a list of applications with a similar purpose :

- [Dup Detector](http://www.freeware-guide.com/rareware/DupDetector.html)
- [DupliFinder](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.duplifinder.com%2F&ei=nFCCVZ6rN4mn8AW7x4LYDw&usg=AFQjCNFPcb3o2qnWsbmY9eYmDubZS5XYKQ&sig2=ZHXTezVrIAvqnM5AKI2w-w&bvm=bv.96041959,d.dGc)
- [DoubleKiller](http://www.bigbangenterprises.de/en/doublekiller/)
- [SimilarImages](https://tn123.org/simimages/)
- [VisiPics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Hope it will help you out, Thanks!!!